# How are iframes vulnerable to attacks

Tags: xss, injection, iframe

I have been doing some research as I am looking to implement a form on anther website using an iframe. I understand that an attacker can change the source code of an iframe to point to a script, but how will this effect everyone else as surely that is client side and not server.

An article I read suggested that hackers will be able to record key strokes from an IE bug, but surely that means modifications to the server side code?

I have enabled sandbox mode with `sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"`. Is this secure enough or should a different approach be taken? .

Answer (score 2):

> An article I read suggested that hackers will be able to record key
>   strokes from an IE bug, but surely that means modifications to the
>   server side code?

The IE bug I believe you are referring to is [mentioned here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting).

> an attacker may create a web page at evil.com, which the attacker
>   controls, and include on the evil.com page a visible frame displaying
>   the login page for example.com. The attacker can hide the frame's
>   borders and expand the frame to cover the entire page, so that it
>   looks to the browser user like he or she is actually visiting
>   example.com The attacker registers some javascript in the main
>   evil.com page which listens for all key events on the page. Normally,
>   this listener would be notified of events only from the main evil.com
>   page -- but because of the browser bug, this listener is notified also
>   of events from the framed example.com page

However, the user would:

1. Have to be using a vulnerable version of Internet Explorer.
2. Already be trusting `evil.com` to enter their credentials for `example.com`. That is, `evil.com` could just as well be displaying something which *looks like* `example.com`'s login page rather than an IFrame.

> I have enabled sandbox mode with sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts".
>   Is this secure enough or should a different approach be taken? .

The main risk if the other website is malicious or compromised, then it can do what it wants *within the IFrame only*. The sandbox attribute is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox), however you may wish to not write the IFrame at all for unsupported browsers. You are not specifying `allow-top-navigation` so they cannot redirect the user away.

The [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will prevent the framed page from manipulating yours. I guess the main risk you're taking is that the site could attempt a browser exploit or a cross-domain attack on another website (e.g. XSS, CSRF) by you sending the user to a site that they have not chosen to trust.

Answer (score -1):

**No, this isn't enough secure.**

- If you havn't set the header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, your site can be display in an iframe. The hacker can use clickjacking : he can put an `iframe` into the `iframe` and with a subtile mix of `CSS` and `HTML`, get the user click on a button which in reality is a link from the iframe of your site to execute an action with `CSRF token`on your website.
- Using iframe hack, the hacker can resize the iframe to fill the entire page. He can insert fake contents such as a fake login page. The user will think about a simple disconnection and relog, giving his logs to the attacker.